# Why TypeScript can't infer assignments of the same object type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this very simplified example of what's happening in my code:

```
interface I {
  n?: number;
  s?: string;
}

const a: I = {
  n: 1,
}

const b: I = {
  n: 2,
  s: 'b',
}

const props = ['n', 's'] as const;

for (const prop of props) {
  if (!a[prop]) {
    // here, I get the following error:
    // TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    a[prop] = b[prop];
  }
}
```

Being `a` and `b` the same types, accessing the same property `prop`... shouldn't it be possible?

- If `b[prop]` is a number, then `a[prop]` should accept numbers
- If `b[prop]` is a string, then `a[prop]` should accept strings
- If `b[prop]` is undefined, is because that prop is optional`?`

So, what am I missing here?

**Update:** Since I simplified my example too much, the answer was to remove the `as const` part... But I think it's due to my environment, because I'm using `strict: true` in `tsconfig.json`...

then, if I try accessing without `as const`, I get this the TS7053 error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'I'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'I'.

Fix adding the `as const` or doing `for(const prop of props as ('n' | 's')[]) {`

and then is when I get my original error (which can be easily fixed with `as any` but I'm trying to avoid that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Typescript doesn't prove every provable property of your code, and isn't trying to. In this particular case, we humans know that the type of `b[prop]` matches the type of `a[prop]` because the property names are the same, but Typescript doesn't see that because it doesn't have a rule which would allow it to.

If we follow Typescript's logic:

- `props` is declared as a tuple of type `['n', 's']`.
- `prop` is declared as an element of `props`, so its type is inferred as `'n' | 's'`.
- Since `b` is declared as type `I`, then `b[prop]` is then inferred as type `I['n' | 's']` which simplifies to `string | number`.
- Since `a` is declared as type `I`, then the *assignment target* `a[prop]` can only receive a value which is assignable to *any* property that `prop` might name; so the assignment target's type is inferred as `I['n'] & I['s']` which simplifies to `string & number`, and then `never`.
- So as far as Typescript is concerned, the assignment `a[prop] = b[prop]` is assigning a value of type `string | number` to an assignment target of type `never`. Since `string | number` is not assignable to `never`, this is a type error.

The simplest fix is to use a type assertion like `b[prop] as any`, i.e. you tell Typescript that you know your code is type-safe so it doesn't need to be checked. Another option is to use a helper function which does the assignments in a way that satisfies Typescript's type-checker:

```js
function copyMissingProperties<T>(a: T, b: T, props: readonly (keyof T)[]): void {
    for (const prop of props) {
        if (!a[prop]) {
            a[prop] = b[prop]; // ok
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `prop`'s type is `keyof T` which is not a union type, so the assignment target doesn't have an intersection type.

Comment: Nice explanation. And yes, I can make it work easily with the `any` _joker_ card... but I'm trying to avoid it, that's why I asked :) -- but I'll try to update the question for a more real-world example

Comment: Yes, `any` is just the simplest way; the `copyProperty` function works without any type assertions.

Comment: that's a great explanation. Sad that there is no proper way to notify that the assignation is correct using a specific keyword or syntax. Using `any` still look like a _trick_

Comment: Exactly, and I'm trying to avoid the use of `any` as much as possible... So... question updated with the explanation of `strict: true` in the compiler options

Comment: ... I showed two options in my answer. The `copyProperty` function does not use `any`, or any other type assertions. As for a *"proper way to notify that the assignment is correct"*, what you seem to mean is a way to tell the compiler not to check the types in the assignment because you know it's safe. That is exactly the intended purpose of type assertions, and any alternative syntax would have exactly the same drawbacks as type assertions do, because it would be semantically the same - it would tell the compiler not to check a certain part of the code.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to ask the compiler to do what I've called [distributive control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051), where it walks through each possible narrowing. You'd say "please make multiple passes over the assignment as if `prop` were a different element of `"n" | "s"` on each pass, and make sure that it always type checks".  It's not going to be implemented, but it would be type-safe without generics or an external function. For now all we can do is assert or use generics. ‍♂️

Comment: @kaya3 true, but it also feels unnatural the need to write a helper just to bypass some TypeScript checks. Calling a function everytime somehow affects the performance of the execution too (even if nowadays the trend is to write for readability more than performance), but it's something to think about... I guess

Comment: @danikaze You can do all the assignments within one function, which might seem more natural and be more performant. I've edited the sample code to do this; it type-checks for the same reason doing one assignment does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I got it to work without making use of casting:

```
interface I {
    n?: number;
    s?: string;
}

const a: I = {
    n: 1,
}

const b: I = {
    n: 2,
    s: 'b',
}

const props: Array<keyof I> = ['n', 's'];

for (const prop of props) {
    if (!a[prop]) {
        const newProp: I = {[prop]: b[prop]};
        Object.assign(a, newProp);
    }
}
```

The trick was to use Object.assign. However, to still ensure the type safety, you can declare the new property as an object of type `I` and then use it in the Object.assign. To make this work in all cases, the best way to do is to just do `Object.assign(a, {[prop]: b[prop]})`

Comment: This is morally equivalent to a type assertion (TS has type assertions; the term "cast" is best avoided because it has connotations of runtime coercion, which definitely does not happen with a TS type assertion), in the sense that `Object.assign(a, {craziness: {foo: "bar"}});` will also "work".

Comment: @jcalz, see the last edit, which should mitigate such concerns

Comment: That's definitely better.  There's still a potential for a false negative here, as can be seen in this intentionally ridiculous example: `const newProp: I = { [Math.random() < 0.5 ? "dog" : "cat"]: b[Math.random() < 0.5 ? "n" : "s"] };` (the computed `[prop]` key gets mapped to a string index signature which can be unsafely narrowed back to `keyof I`, and the value assigned isn't necessarily guaranteed to be of the right type).  I'm not trying to discourage this approach so much as to warn about pitfalls that I've seen people fall into.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

the problem is with this line

`const props = ['n', 's'] as const;`

change it to

`const props = ['n', 's'];`

check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-so-60041340)

Comment: true, that works. Reasoning behind? Anyways, it was my fault because in my real example, this solution doesn't work... let me update the question :)

Comment: So it's by being blurry about the real type of the data that typescript accept it ? Looks like a tricks. `'n' | 's'` should work in theory. Could you explain why It shouldn't?

Comment: why downvoting?

Answer (score -1):

I tried like that and its work, and you should remove as const value on props definition

```
interface I {
  n?: number;
  s?: string;
}

const a: I = {
  n: 1,
}

const b: I = {
  n: 2,
  s: 'b',
}

const props = ['n', 's'];

for (const prop of props) {
  if (!a[prop]) {
    a[prop] = b[prop];
    console.log(a, b);
  }
}
```

Result is:
{n: 1, s: "b"} {n: 2, s: "b"}